# How to save Spark mllib KMeans model? model.save leads to empty dirs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I have a stream source and I am trying to derive the clustering K-Means model first. Later I plan to load this model to StreamingKMeans. Here is how far I got but the save operation leads to empty folder /data.

```
srtLabeledPoints.foreachRDD{ rdd => {
   import sparkSession.implicits._   

   val testTrain = rdd.randomSplit(Array(0.3, 0.7))      
   val test = testTrain(0)
   val train = testTrain(1)

   val model = kMeans.run(train.map(f => f.features))  
   val a = model.predict(test.map(f => f.features))
   println("******************")       
   a.take(50).foreach(println)
   val b = model.save(sparkSession.sparkContext, "/mnt/c/Users/ssss/ml/oooModel3" + a.id)
   println("******************")       
   }
   rdd.unpersist()
 }
```

where kmeans is the following

```
val kMeans   = new org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans()
  .setK(20) //# of clusters
  .setSeed(31)
```

I see the classification (between 0 to 19) displayed on the console (with the take operation). But /data is empty and /metadata has a 1Kb file with the following contents:

```
{"class":"org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel","version":"2.0","k":20,"distanceMeasure":"euclidean","trainingCost":5.147088938203919E11}
```

What am I doing wrong in order to save the model?

Comment: Have you tried to load the model?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 - According to the docs here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#mllib-operations , I seem to have to first save the model from a batch or offline run before i can load it to a streaming run.